# Пытаюсь написать слайдер, который бы менял фоновое изображение

Tags: javascript, слайдер

Доброго времени суток!

Какие условия указать для того, чтобы смена картинок была по кругу. Буду рад любой помощи или подсказке.

```js
    var background = [
      'url(http://www.expressphotography.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/blog-
      background - photography.jpg) 0 0 no - repeat fixed;
    ',
    'url(http://www.powerpointhintergrund.com/uploads/beautiful-space-
    background - template - 24. jpeg) 0 0 no - repeat fixed;
    ',
    'url(http://seoblognik.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/fon-dlja-tvittera-
    10. jpg) 0 0 no - repeat fixed;
    '
    ],
    i = 0,
      sliderHeader = document.querySelector('.header');

    document.querySelector('#sliderButtonLeft').onclick = sliderToLeft;
    document.querySelector('#sliderButtonRight').onclick = sliderToRight;

    function sliderToLeft() {
      for (; i < background.length; i++) {
        sliderHeader.style.background = background[i];
      }
      if (i = 0) {
        sliderHeader.style.background = background[0];
      }
    }

    function sliderToRight() {
      for (var i = background.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        sliderHeader.style.background = background[i];
      }
      if (i = 0) {
        sliderHeader.style.background = background[0];
      }
```

```css
.header {
      position: relative;
      background: url(http://seoblognik.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/fon-dlja-tvittera-10.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
      height: 64em;
      transition: all ease 0.5s;
    }

    #sliderButtonLeft {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      left: 500px;
      top: 300px;
      outline: none;
    }

    #sliderButtonRight {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      right: 500px;
      top: 300px;
      outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
      <input type="image" id="sliderButtonLeft" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-back-512.png">
      <input type="image" id="sliderButtonRight" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-256.png">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, по - другому надо было делать. Может кому пригодится.

```
    var background = [
        'url(http://www.expressphotography.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/blog-background-photography.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;',

        'url(http://www.powerpointhintergrund.com/uploads/beautiful-space-background-template-24.jpeg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;',
        'url(http://seoblognik.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/fon-dlja-tvittera-10.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;'
      ],
      i = 1,
      sliderHeader = document.querySelector('.header');

    document.querySelector('#sliderButtonLeft').onclick = sliderToLeft;
    document.querySelector('#sliderButtonRight').onclick = sliderToRight;

    function sliderToLeft() {
      i++;
      if (i > (background.length - 1)) {
        i = 0;
      }
      sliderHeader.style.background = background[i];

    }

    function sliderToRight() {
  i--;
  if (i < 0) {
    i = background.length - 1;
  }
  sliderHeader.style.background = background[i];
}
```